# TypeError: yup.string.require is not a function. (In 'yup.string.require()', 'yup.string.require' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, react-native, formik, yup

I am using formik for making form and yup for form validation. Yup is not working in my form.

i am following a tutorial in that same code is working but in my case it is not working

I tried a lot but i am not able to find out the error.
i also went for documentation and my cose is same as mentioned in documentation but still getting the error.

**Error**   :

```
**TypeError: yup.string.require is not a function. (In 'yup.string.require()', 'yup.string.require' is undefined)
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue**
```

here is my code

```
import React from "react";
import { Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as yup from 'yup';

import AppButton from "../components/AppButton";
import AppText from "../components/AppText";
import AppTextInput from "../components/AppTextInput";
import ScreenComponent from "../components/ScreenComponent";


let validationSchema  = yup.object().shape({
  email : yup.string.required().email().label('Email'),
  password : yup.string().required().min(4).label('Password')
});

function LoginScreen(props) {
  return (
    <ScreenComponent>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
        onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
        validationSchema = {validationSchema}
      >
      {({handleChange,handleSubmit,errors})=>(

        <>
          <Image
            style={styles.logo}
            source={require("../assets/logo-red.png")}
          />
          <AppTextInput
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            icon="email"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
            placeholder="Email"
            textContentType="emailAddress"
          />
          <AppText style = {{color:'red'}}>{errors.email}</AppText>
          <AppTextInput
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            icon="lock"
            onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
            placeholder="Password"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            textContentType="password"
          />
          <AppText style = {{color:'red'}}>{errors.password}</AppText>
          <AppButton
            title="Login"
            onPress={handleSubmit}
          />
        </>
      )}
      </Formik>
    </ScreenComponent>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  logo: {
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginBottom: 20,
    marginTop: 50,
  },
});

export default LoginScreen;
```

Comment: `email : yup.string.required().email().label('Email'),` - in this line you are not calling `string()` like you are doing the next line

Comment: thanks . a signgle silly mistakes tooks 1 hour. thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Did Spelling Mistake
Need to change

```
email : yup.string.required().email().label('Email'),
```

to

```
email : yup.string().required().email().label('Email'),
```